# Change wallpaper using java

Tags: java, windows, jna

I found this code on the internet for changing windows wallpaper using JNA library and it works just as I wanted but only with images outside of .jar program (here is a code)

```
public class Wallpaper {

public Wallpaper() {
    User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, "C:\\Users\\Public\\Pictures\\Sample Pictures\\bg.jpg", 1);
}
public static interface User32 extends Library {

    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class, W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);

    boolean SystemParametersInfo(int one, int two, String s, int three);
}
```

}

is there a way to get the file from resources ? It doesn't work when I replace the file path with this

```
getClass().getResource("bg.jpg").getPath()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getResource` retrieves resources from whereever your class files live, and this could be a network, generated on the fly, or, most likely, from within a jar file, and **those aren't files**. The windows API you are calling requires a file.

Thus, the answer is :What you want, is impossible.

But you can work around it.

You can get the resource as a stream, open a file someplace, transfer the bytes over ('copying' the resource to a file) and then provide the file. Something like:

```
Path p = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home"), "backgrounds", "bg.jpg");
Files.createDirectories(p.getParent());
try (InputStream in = Wallpaper.class.getResourceAsStream("bg.jpg");
  OutputStream out = Files.newOutputStream(p)) {

    in.transferTo(out);
}
User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, p.getAbsolutePath().toString(), 1);
```

NOTE: The correct usage of `getResource` is not via `getClass()` but: `Wallpaper.class.getResource`. getClass() breaks if subclassing.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I ended up copying the file to user.home, setting the wallpaper and removing the file afterwards. so nearly the same thing as you suggested.

Comment: There's a rather large risk that deleting the file afterwards means that windows will 'lose' the background (show uniform black instead) next time the user reboots their system. Make sure you test that.

Comment: Fortunately that didn't happen. Now I have trouble with copying the image from resources after the program has been compiled and also the java program doesn't see the command for changing the wallpaper as it's own process so sometimes happens that the image is removed before it finishes changing the wallpaper and this results in uniform black background. I don't want to use Thread.sleep() because the time it takes to set the wallpaper may be different from computer to computer so on slower PCs it might result in black BG anyway.